# Upload image and information

Tags: php, html

I want to create form that allow users to upload their photo, name and email then save it in  a database?
I have tried this so far http://www.reconn.us/file_uploading.html

Comment: What problem did you encounter with the solution in the link you provided?

Comment: You tried it, but it didn't work? Please be more specific. In its current form, your question doesn't fit the format required here. Read the [faq]. Also, try to search on StackOverflow, you'll likely find related questions

Comment: Please include all the information in your question. A question which depends on some external link that is going to change/disappear is not acceptable.

Comment: @thaJeztah i found same questions here but there is no answer for them yet

Comment: you cant store images in a sql database

Comment: @BrokenPixels the one i tried didn't allow me to choose the image i want to upload as the button doesn't work.beside i need to upload image and other user information to the database any idea how can i do that?

Comment: @meagar i probably found similar questions asked without answer i really need an answer.

Comment: @Suma Sultan, @manticore, Get the image as the link explains, then read it back and store it as in a `BLOB`-type field in the database. See [here](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/40286-tutorial-storing-images-in-mysql-with-php/) for a worked example.

Comment: @SumaSultan Then go hire a programmer. If you want to post questions here you have to follow the rules.

Comment: @Broken Pixels, thank you for that link!

Comment: Added my comment as a answer, since it seems to be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the image as your link explains, then read in the temporary file and store it in a `BLOB`-type field in the database. See [here](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/40286-tutorial-storing-images-in-mysql-with-php/) for a full example.

---

```
// Make sure the user actually
// selected and uploaded a file
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {

// Temporary file name stored on the server
$tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

// Read the file
$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$data = addslashes($data);
fclose($fp);


// Create the query and insert
// into our database.
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images ";
$query .= "(image) VALUES ('$data')";
$results = mysql_query($query, $link);

// Print results
print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

}
else {
print "No image selected/uploaded";
}

// Close our MySQL Link
mysql_close($link);
?>
```